# Using CSS background-size gives blurry image in WebView, on high PPI screen

Tags: android, css, webview, retina-display

I'm having trouble displaying high dpi images in an Android WebView.

Firstly, I'm using this directive in my HTML:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Background images are being specified as follows in my CSS:

```
.button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    /* button.png is really 200x100 */
    background: url('../img/button.png') no-repeat 50% 50%;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

On Chrome for Android, this image appears very crisp. However in a WebView the image is blurry - as though it was 72dpi being upscaled.

Oddly, if I specify:

```
<meta name='viewport' content='target-densitydpi=device-dpi'>
```

then the image appears crisp, albeit the rest of the page is at half resolution too.

I've added things like `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` and `android:anyDensity="true"` to my `AndroidManifest.xml` but none seem to make any difference.

Has anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Might have something to do with [this bug](http://mbudm.com/2011/03/android-css-background-image-blurriness/)?

Comment: Did you find an answer?  I am facing the same issue...

Comment: I think so. When used a background image that was an odd number of pixels in width or height, centring with `50% 50%` aligns the image to half pixels resulting in a blurry image. If I round the image up to even pixeled width and height or align to `left top` the image appears sharp.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
img{
image-rendering: optimizeQuality;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn’t seem to solve the issue (tested on Android 4.3.1). I don’t think Chrome or Android support that property – https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering#Browser_compatibility

Comment: I haven't noticed any improvement - the image in the webview still looks washed out, even with that style update.

Answer (score 0):

Force the hardware acceleration in css will give you a 'clear' image.

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
```

More info https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/i/image-rendering/